# Django forms how to get cleaned_data from fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Im creating simple dynamic `form fields` that user can add their form fields and all fields are related to `category` model. I want that when user select `category` named `car` then show them related `fields` to that car.

**my structure:**

```
class Category:
    name = ...


class Field:
    label = ...
    category = ForeignKey(Category)


class FieldValue:
    value = ...
    field = ForeignKey(Field)
```

My problem is how can I generate my form and how to retrieve data from `form.cleaned_data` and so I can add records to `FieldValue` model. I created a form and its working fine for rendering using `__init__`. And I want to retrieve data from rendered form fields.

**my form:**

```
class CategoryFieldsForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, category_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CategoryFieldsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        fields = Field.objects.filter(category_id=category_id)

        for i in range(1, len(fields)):
            for field in fields:
                self.fields[field.slug] = forms.CharField()

    def clean(self):
        # how can i validate

    def save(self):
        print(self.cleaned_data)
        # how can i save fields
```

**my view:**

```
def some_create_view(request, category_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CategoryFieldsForm(category_id)
        form.save()

    form = CategoryFieldsForm(category_id)

    return render(request, 'create.html', {'form': form})
```

When I submit my form `CategoryFieldsForm` object has no attribute `cleaned_data` is showing.

Comment: You need to call `form.is_valid()`.

Comment: Is it really checking that form is valid or not in my situation?

Comment: I tried but it is always returning false even I filled correctly

Comment: Oh its working now what ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the form with the POST data, then call `form.is_valid()` before you can access `form.cleaned_data`.

```
def some_create_view(request, category_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CategoryFieldsForm(category_id, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

Comment: Thank you! But in my case `form.save()` is not working. How can I save all the inputs to `FieldValue` ?

Comment: You have three related models which makes it slightly complex, so I can't writie your save method for you. You need to fetch the category from the `category_id`, then loop through the keys and values of `self.cleaned_data` and set the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about form.is_valid() [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django).

> A Form instance has an is_valid() method, which runs validation routines for all its fields. When this method is called, if all fields contain valid data, it will:
>
> 1) return True
>
> 2) place the form’s data in its cleaned_data attribute.

```
def some_create_view(request, category_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CategoryFieldsForm(category_id, request.POST)
        if form.valid():                
            # you should be able to access the form cleaned data here
            ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) and others. It was more simple error that I was thinking.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CategoryFieldsForm(category_id, request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            print(form)
        else:
            print(form.errors)

    form = CategoryFieldsForm(category_id)
```

I was just forget that pass `request.POST` to my form.